# Is there a way to subdivide only largest triangles?

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I have a STL mesh from the internet, which has curved surfaces (higher resolution) and flat surfaces (lower resolution/large faces). This causes issues when sculpting at interfaces of those two areas. Is there a way to break down larger triangles into smaller ones automatically, without affecting the shape of the whole object and without breaking down those already small triangles?
I also do not want to select those triangles manually, because I think such an operation should be automatic.

[image: example interface of larger triangles and smaller triangles]

Comment: Is this a problem dyntopo would solve?

Answer (score 1):

How about a Geonode setup like this:

[image]

Can  be applied recursively…

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, this is slightly more complicated than I was expecting. But in case there is no simpler method, it would have been great to turn it into a plugin or add-on.

Comment: I doubt anyone would use such an addon, because I think the topology produced is bad.

Comment: Yet, it is far better than the state before. e.g. for sculpting. Instead of exponentially increasing the number of meshes, this approach is far better.

Comment: @SarenTasciyan is it? Imagine that you want to sculpt a small hole in the middle of the cube's side. Before subdivision you effect either of the big triangles. After such subdivision you hit a much smaller triangle(s), but they still go across the entire cube, so you can sculpt a valley going across the entire cube, but not a small hole.

Comment: I see the point, it is ok on some edges but not on others. An improvement could be to divide each triangle always by half by drawing an altitude from the corner with the largest angle?